# can computers play word association games?

Tags: natural-language, association-rules

Suppose I give you these 6 English words:

*circle, low, Brian, sentence, support, wild*

and ask you to find a 7th word that is associated with all of them. You probably already know which one it is.

Each word is obviously associated with many other words, e.g. *circle* could be associated with *friends*, *pi*, *area*...; *sentence* could be associated with *judge*, *grammar*, *phrase*...; etc.
Each association can be stronger or weaker, perhaps depending on its frequency in naturally occurring language.
So the task would seem to be: intersect all the sets of words associated with each of the 6 'seeds', and find what is left. But with some measurement of the strength of the results.

Could a computer 'play' this game? Are there any machine learning methods that could do this? I'm thinking association rules or something related to text mining, but I am not sure.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a many projects related to machine learning and word associations.

I think that this is the most useful for you: https://wordassociations.net/en/about

I just tested the two games presented here and honestly it is impressive: https://research.google.com/semantris